# How to get a user to exit out the while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to a while loop gooing, but then i went the user to enter 5 to exit out of the loop. I am in python 3

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to the List Info Checker")
    printMenu()
    printValue = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 5(inclusive): ")
    while printValue != 5:
        if printValue == 1:
            print("1")
        elif printValue == 2:
           # allTheSame()
            print("2")
        elif printValue == 3:
           # allDifferent()
            print("3")
        elif printValue == 4:
           # sortThis()
            print("4")

main()
```

Comment: Is this python 3 or python 2?

Comment: @Whud explained it below. Also if you are stucked in an infinite loop and want to stop the program you can use the interrupt key `ctrl-c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to break out of a `while` loop

1. Have the statement change in some way so that it is no longer `True`
2. use the `break` command to break out of the 'lowest level loop'

Because the user input is only asked before the loop there is no way it could change after the loop started causing an endless loop. If the input was inside the loop it could be broken by the user putting a 5 in because it is asked every time the loop restarts:

```
printValue = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 5(inclusive): ")

while printValue != 5:

    if printValue == 1:
        print("1")
    elif printValue == 2:
       # allTheSame()
        print("2")
    elif printValue == 3:
       # allDifferent()
        print("3")
    elif printValue == 4:
       # sortThis()
        print("4")

    printValue = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 5(inclusive): ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prompt for the input in the loop, otherwise the its always just checking the same value entered the first time. try this:

```
def main():
print("Welcome to the List Info Checker")
printMenu()
printValue = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 5(inclusive): ")
while printValue != 5:
    if printValue == 1:
        print("1")
    elif printValue == 2:
       # allTheSame()
        print("2")
    elif printValue == 3:
       # allDifferent()
        print("3")
    elif printValue == 4:
       # sortThis()
        print("4")
    printValue = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 5(inclusive): ")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "break"

```
print("Welcome to the List Info Checker")
printMenu()
while True:
    if printValue == 1:
        print("1")
    elif printValue == 2:
       # allTheSame()
        print("2")
    elif printValue == 3:
       # allDifferent()
        print("3")
    elif printValue == 4:
       # sortThis()
        print("4")
    elif printValue == 5:
        break
```

or for the last two lines

```
    else:
        break
```